# Using Hadoop and Spark on Docker containers

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I want to use Big Data Analytics for my work. I have already implemented all the docker stuff creating containers within containers. I am new to Big Data however and I have come to know that using Hadoop for HDFS and using Spark instead of MapReduce on Hadoop itself is the best way for websites and applications when speed matters (is it?). Will this work on my Docker containers? It'd be very helpful if someone could direct me somewhere to learn more.

Comment: Web applications in hadoop/spark? sorry, but I don't understand your question. Maybe you are mistaking apache spark bigdata (http://spark.apache.org/)  and spark java web framework (http://sparkjava.com/)?

Comment: I'm sorry but IMO this question is all over the place, it covers multiple topics such as analytics/big data (what ever that is), Docker, Hadoop/HDFS, Spark and MapReduce. When it comes to "will this work on my Docker containers" I would say yes, most things can be made to work on top of Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try playing with Cloudera QuickStart Docker Image to get started. Please take a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/. This docker image supports single-node deployment of Cloudera's Hadoop platform, and Cloudera Manager. Also this docker image supports spark too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working anymore since Cloudera changed its trial to the cloud